# Karate - How to run a specific scenario only in one environment?

Tags: karate

Consider there are 100 scenarios and I want to run 99 scenarios in prod environment and 100 on stage environment .

Is there a way to achieve this in karate ?

Things I tried 
1. Create a feature file with 1 scenario and another feature file with remaining 99
2. Add tag to the 1 scenario file
3. Ignore that while running

But then when I use it in jenkins job I have to run one command to run on both machines so would not work

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best solution for this case is the [`karate.abort()`](https://github.com/intuit/karate#karate-abort) API:

So in the "special" scenario #100 - you can do this:

```
Scenario:
  * eval if (karate.env == 'prod') karate.abort()
  # normal scenario steps
```

Please note that there are [advanced options for tag selectors](https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/505) in Karate 0.9.0 onwards - but just stick to the solution above please :)

Answer (score 5):

Tag the 100th scenario with @hundred and just run the following command when you want to run 99 scenarios

```
mvn test -Dkarate.options="--tags ~@hundred"
```

And simply run `mvn test` when you want to run all tests.

You can tag a scenario

```
@hundred
Scenario: the scenario only played in one case
Given <...>
```

But you can also tag a Feature

```
@hundred
Feature: The feature containing the scenario only played in one case

Background:
* <..>

Scenario: <...>
```

Edit after your answer :
You could use a second runtime variable :

```
mvn test -Dkarate.options="--tags ~@{variable2}" -Dkarate.env={variable}
```

Or even use the same runtime variable :

```
mvn test -Dkarate.options="--tags ~@{variable}" -Dkarate.env={variable}
```

And that maybe wouldn't be the best solution, but you can add @Prod to the 99 scenarios, and @Stage to all of them, and switch the command to this :

```
mvn test -Dkarate.options="--tags @{variable}" -Dkarate.env={variable}
```

It's a bit longer to do, but at least the tag(s) on each feature/scenario will correspond to the case(s) in which they are launched

Comment: The problem is I cant use different commands for running on different environments as the setup is mvn test -Dkarate.options="--tags ~@hundred" -Dkarate.env={variable}

This variable is value is set at runtime as Prod or Staging when starting jenkins job

Comment: @Adrien I think I have a better solution

Comment: I had no doubts that you would provide a cleaner way to do this which I wouldn't have thought of.