# The best conditional logic for match and match each case

Tags: karate

so, I want to use conditional logic in my code, which the condition is when I got `response.response_code == '00'` so it will run

```
And match response == res_3[0]
And match each response.data.bills == res_3[1]
```

And if `response.response_code != '00'` , it will run

```
And match response == res_3
And match each response.data.bills == res_3
```

so, what is the best conditional logic for this case ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read the docs please: https://github.com/intuit/karate#conditional-logic

Use a second feature file:

```
* eval if (response.response_code != '00') karate.call('it-will-run.feature')
```

Note: you can't use `match` where JavaScript is expected, refer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53961806/143475

Comment: I already read about conditional-logic before, but i wanna use conditional logic without call another file, like if else in this contexts it possible ?

Comment: no. you can look at `karate.abort()` as a hack: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54310853/143475